# Copy live database to development-server

Tags: mysql, database, deployment, jenkins

We've a productive MySQL-Database which private user data inside (passwordhashes, ips, emails etc).
When a developer run a buildjob in jenkins on his developer-vm, we want to include a copy of the live-database so that he get an environment which is very similar to our production one. But we've to clean up the production database before it is copied to the dev-server because of 2 reasons:

- Developers shouldn't get a copy of all our user data like hashed passwords or emails
- The database is big, so we want to delete some of the contents that the dev has a few real data sets for testing, but not > 100k, that will have no benefit and will increase the time which the dump take

I thought about this and tried a few things, but I found no method which is fast and will do the job. 
My first idea was to make a dump of all the data by mysqldump, import it on the dev-machine, and send some MySQL-Querys for setting placeholders instead of private data

```
UPDATE user_data SET email = "dev@example.com" [...]
```

On the one hand this is slow because it have to copy the huge database AND do the querys. And I don't like it that all of our user-data is on the dev-machine, even for a short time period. I would like it better when the data gets cleaned first and then exported to the dev-machine. This would be possible by copying the database in a temp one on the production system, then clean the data, export it and delete the copied database on the production system. But this also created a lot of overhead.

What is a good and fast method for doing this? 
I thought about something like mysqldump with replacing the data, so that no overhead is created. But i can't find any tool which can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough room for two databases on the production server?  If so, make a developer db on the same server (or any server, really) which is a nightly dump of production, minus all the sensitive information and bulk.

Developers get access to only this "developer" database, from the production server, which you know has been pruned of anything sensitive.  As a bonus, they could connect directly to it, and possibly never need to download it.

Comment: The point is that we've multiplice developers, so everyone of them should get his own dev-machine with a copy of the db. From time to time it would be neccessary to deploy the actual production db to the dev-machines, because the dev-databases are no longer up to date. So I would like to build an automatic solution, that the devs can include a copy of the actual prodution database on their dev-machine without sensitive user-data by using a checkbox in jenkins.

Comment: Right, so have a common development database maintained on some server that they all connect to and/or download.  That way, the production DB is never downloaded (for development)